# How does Haskell process a list?

Tags: haskell

A few of us at work have been reading some on Haskell and we were talking about some of the concepts yesterday.  The question came up with Haskell being a lazy language, how does it handle retrieving the nth element of a list?

For example, if we had

```
 [2,4..10000000] !! 200
```

Would it actually populate the list up to 200 elements?  Or does it compile it down into an equation similar to

```
n*step + firstValue
```

and then return that calculation?  The reason this came up was someone was trying to come up with an example where a program would easily run out of memory, and the thought of traversing down a (sufficiently large) list was the first candidate that came up.

Comment: Optimizing compilers aside, one would hope that the programmer would perform this optimization manually.

Comment: @DanBurton true.  This was a discussion on trying to understand the theory.  As of right now we aren't using Haskell at work, and don't see it happening in the near future, but we were just talking concepts.

Comment: you may be interested in checking out GHC's [Rewrite rules](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.2.1/html/users_guide/rewrite-rules.html) which allow you to define your own optimizations for the compiler to utilize (e.g. for your own libraries).

Comment: @DanBurton how about `g k n m = sum . take k $ cycle [n,n+2..m]`? Here too, manually? :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, it will produce the first 201 elements of the list before returning. However, since this list is not accessible from anywhere else in your program, the initial bits will be eligible for garbage collection as it goes along, so it will run in constant space (but linear time) with a naive implementation.

Of course, an optimizing compiler might be able to do a lot better. Since your expression is a constant, it might even evaluate it at compile time.

Comment: But be careful; if the list generation isn't as nice, garbage collection may be prevented. Consider `iterate (+2) 2 !! 10000000`, each list element refers to the previous, so nothing can be collected immediately.

Comment: @DanielFischer a strict version of `iterate` will run in constant space.

Comment: @is7s Sure, the point is that references to the beginning of the list prevent garbage collection. `iterate` is just an example that easily creates such references.

Comment: Beware the trap of the sufficiently smart compiler.  AFAIK, no existing Haskell compiler will optimize this expression better than linear time, and it being theoretically possible does not really help.

Answer (score 9):

> Would it actually populate the list up to 200 elements?

In a naive implementation, yes.

> Or does it compile it down into an equation similar to `n*step + firstValue`?

An optimizing Haskell compiler might do that, though I wouldn't expect an actual implementation to perform this optimization.

The point is that Haskell is so strictly formalized that it's possible to prove these two options equivalent in terms of their return value on an idealized machine, so it's up to the compiler to choose either one. The language standard (the *Haskell Report*) just describes what value should be returned, not how it should be computed.

Answer (score 7):

The term "laziness" has a precise mathematical meaning which you can learn from books on call by need lambda calculus. The layman definition "nothing is evaluated until the result is needed elsewhere" is just a metaphor for newbies. It's a simplification so in complex situations like this one understanding of the full theory is required to explain what's going on.

The precise semantic *requires* the compiler not to evaluate list elements until a pattern match on them are performed. It's not a matter of optimization - it *always* must be the case. So if you calculate a !! 3, the very minimum you get (it depends on definition of a) is the following:

_ : _ : _ : 5 : _

here by _ I mean "not evaluated". You can learn to understand what is evaluated and what is not by learning lambda calculus. Until then, you can use GHCi debugger to see:

```
Prelude> let l = [1..10]
Prelude> let x = l !! 5
Prelude> :set -fprint-evld-with-show
Prelude> :print x
x = (_t1::Integer)
Prelude> :print l
l = (_t2::[Integer])
Prelude> x
6
Prelude> :print l
l = 1 : 2 : 3 : 4 : 5 : 6 : (_t3::[Integer])
```

Note that l is not evaluated at all until you print x. Print invokes show, and show performs a series of pattern matching. In this particular case the first elements of list get evaluated because of pattern matching inside implementation of [1..10] (actually it gets translated into a usual application `enumFromTo 1 10`). However, if we add m = map (+1) l, we note that more elements of m are unevaluated, because map has less pattern matching than [1..10]:

```
Prelude> let m = map (+1) l
Prelude> :print m
m = (_t4::[Integer])
Prelude> m !! 5
7
Prelude> :print m
m = (_t5::Integer) : (_t6::Integer) : (_t7::Integer) :
    (_t8::Integer) : (_t9::Integer) : 7 : (_t10::[Integer])
```

I repeat, it is possible to recognize easily what gets evaluated and what is not, and in what exact order evaluation is performed, but you need to learn the precise semantics - just learning a metaphor doesn't let you understand the details. The final example is

```
> Prelude> let ll = zipWith (+) l (tail l) Prelude> ll !! 5 13 Prelude>
> :print l l = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

So depending on (statically known!) structure of your program, many situations are possible. At the very minimum when you evaluate list !! 3, you get `_ : _ : _ : 5 : _`. At the very maximum you get full list evaluated : `1 : 2 : 3 : 4 : 5 : 6 : 7 : 8 : 9 : 10 : []`.

I could easily construct all these 4 sample situations - so you can learn too, but it requires some math background.

Comment: +1! This answer is one of the best I've ever seen on lazy evaluation in Haskell!

Answer (score 6):

As larsmans said it is up to the compiler, to decide what to do. But I would expect GHC to populate the list up till the 201st element. But it would not evaluate those elements.

Assuming there is a factorial function:

```
factorial n = product [1..n]
```

The following code will print the factorial of 200, it will create the first 201 cells of the list, but it will evaluate only one factorial.

```
print $ [ factorial n | n <- [0,1..] ] !! 201
```

Answer (score 6):

It depends on x in -Ox

```
import Criterion.Main
import qualified Data.Vector as V
import qualified Data.List.Stream as S

naive _ = [2,4 .. k] !! n

eq _ = n*2 + 2

uvector _ = V.enumFromThenTo 2 4 k V.! n

stream _ = [2,4 .. k] S.!! n

n = 100000
k = 10*n

main = defaultMain [ bgroup "range"
    [ bench "naive"   $ whnf naive n
    , bench "eq"      $ whnf eq n
    , bench "uvector" $ whnf uvector n
    , bench "stream"  $ whnf stream n
    ]]

-- -Odph -fforce-recomp -fllvm
--
--benchmarking range/naive
--mean: 11.83244 ns, lb 11.39379 ns, ub 12.90468 ns, ci 0.950
--std dev: 3.304705 ns, lb 1.189680 ns, ub 6.155017 ns, ci 0.950
--
--benchmarking range/eq
--mean: 7.911626 ns, lb 7.741035 ns, ub 8.122809 ns, ci 0.950
--std dev: 970.2263 ps, lb 828.3840 ps, ub 1.177933 ns, ci 0.950
--
--benchmarking range/uvector
--mean: 10.74393 ns, lb 10.30107 ns, ub 11.81737 ns, ci 0.950
--std dev: 3.268982 ns, lb 861.2390 ps, ub 5.811662 ns, ci 0.950
--
--benchmarking range/stream
--mean: 12.34206 ns, lb 11.71146 ns, ub 14.07016 ns, ci 0.950
--std dev: 4.959039 ns, lb 2.124692 ns, ub 10.40687 ns, ci 0.950

-- -O3 -fforce-recomp -fasm

--benchmarking range/naive
--mean: 11.11646 ns, lb 10.83341 ns, ub 11.82991 ns, ci 0.950
--std dev: 2.048823 ns, lb 289.9484 ps, ub 3.752569 ns, ci 0.950
--
--benchmarking range/eq
--mean: 8.535535 ns, lb 8.297940 ns, ub 9.067161 ns, ci 0.950
--std dev: 1.771753 ns, lb 933.7552 ps, ub 2.843637 ns, ci 0.950
--
--benchmarking range/uvector
--mean: 11.12599 ns, lb 10.88839 ns, ub 11.71998 ns, ci 0.950
--std dev: 1.734431 ns, lb 306.4149 ps, ub 3.123837 ns, ci 0.950
--
--benchmarking range/stream
--mean: 10.73798 ns, lb 10.42936 ns, ub 11.45102 ns, ci 0.950
--std dev: 2.301690 ns, lb 1.184686 ns, ub 3.877275 ns, ci 0.950


-- -O0 -fforce-recomp -fasm

--benchmarking range/naive
--mean: 1.742292 ms, lb 1.693402 ms, ub 1.934525 ms, ci 0.950
--std dev: 432.1991 us, lb 70.44581 us, ub 1.006263 ms, ci 0.950
--
--benchmarking range/eq
--mean: 37.66248 ns, lb 36.37912 ns, ub 42.66504 ns, ci 0.950
--std dev: 11.91135 ns, lb 1.493463 ns, ub 28.17839 ns, ci 0.950
--
--benchmarking range/uvector
--mean: 36.32181 ms, lb 35.41175 ms, ub 38.63195 ms, ci 0.950
--std dev: 6.887482 ms, lb 2.532232 ms, ub 13.47616 ms, ci 0.950
--
--benchmarking range/stream
--mean: 1.731072 ms, lb 1.692072 ms, ub 1.875080 ms, ci 0.950
--std dev: 342.2325 us, lb 81.77006 us, ub 792.2414 us, ci 0.950
```

Well, in this simple case GHC (7.0.2) really IS sufficiently smart.

Comment: GHC's base now supports streams which is why the results are similar. uvector's terrible performance in -O0 is expected because it completely relies on streaming to get any decent performance. Also, your comments indicate you use uvector but your module import indicates you use Vector. In any case it'd be nice to look at Data.Vector.Unboxed performance rather than Data.Vector

Answer (score 3):

With GHC you can write stuff like

```
myVal = [2,4..] !! 200
```

which look for an element in an infinite list. So indeed, it does not allocate the full list. See http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Memory_leak for an example of memory leaks in Haskell.

Answer (score 2):

All implementations I'm aware of would poulate the list as far as needed. Indeed, traversing a sufficiently large list can easily make you run out of memory, you just have to arrange it so that the part you already stepped through can't be garbage collected, e.g.

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    let xs :: [Int]
        xs = [1 .. 10^9]
    print (xs !! 123456789)
    print (xs !! 2)
```

compiling it down to `fromIntegral n*step + start` is a tricky business. Whether that's valid depends on the type. If the type of list elements is bounded and `n` is large enough, `xs !! n` would throw an "index too large" exception, but the arithmetic may be perfectly well-defined. So the transformation would be valid for `Integer`, but not generally.